# Redirect and then render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, so real quick, I am using a file upload plugin http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input to upload my images. The plugin expects some sort of response from the server, and i want to send back an empty json object.

But when the images are uploaded, I also need to redirect immediately to another place so people can sort of make changes to the order.

Rails says I can't use render and redirect, but says i can redirect and return.
How do i redirect and return the empty json object??

```
 def create
if !params[:images].nil? 
  package = Package.first 
  @photos = Array.new   
  @order = current_user.orders.new 
  @order.save  

  @order.order_items.each{|d| d.delete} #Stupid hack to prevent creation of fake order items. Don't know what is causing this yet

  params["images"].each do |i|  
    photo = current_user.photos.create  
    photo.write(i.original_filename,  i.read)
    photo.save
    @order.order_items.create(photo_id: photo.id, size_id: package.size_id, material_id: package.material_id)

  end
  redirect_to edit_order_path(@order) and return


else
  flash[:danger] = "Please select at least one photo to upload"
  redirect_to upload_photos_path
end
```

end

Comment: when the docs/ error message say "redirect and return" they just mean return from the current method - the only response the browser receives is the redirect. You'll probably need some client side code to do the redirect.

Comment: Ahh, I thought the return was like the php return..thing is, i am a php developer, i am just standing in to help someone on the RoR code. But, let me see what i can do on the client side for the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the upload plugin you're using is expecting a JSON response and you would like to redirect after a successful upload, then you'll need to do it client side.

If you're not using Rails 4 or Turbolinks, you can simply redirect via `window.location.replace`. From your Rails code it looks like you're batch uploading in which case you'll want to assign a callback to the `filebatchuploadsuccess` event as per [the docs](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-filebatchuploadsuccess)

Example:

```
$('#fileinputid').on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    // files have been successfully uploaded, redirect
    window.location.replace( '/your_path_here' );
});
```

If you are using Turbolinks, the above code will be exactly the same except that instead of `window.location.replace`, you can use `Turbolinks.visit`

Example:

```
$('#fileinputid').on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    // files have been successfully uploaded, redirect
    Turbolinks.visit( '/your_path_here' );
});
```

Comment: This should work...problem is, i want to redirect the user to the page which expects the order id as a parameter...now since i do the render like render :json => @order, how do i access that json object, so i can then go a head and redirect them to the page? I thought this would be the data, but it is not in there.

Comment: I have figured it out...i had to access data.response.id. thanks

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if it helped you with your original question? Thanks.